# Is this a valid example of the tangent vector a linear map from a smooth function to the reals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is intended to give an example of the tangent vector at a point $p$ along a smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ on a manifold as a linear map (directional derivative) from a smooth function $f$ to the real numbers constructed as

$$f \mapsto (f \circ \gamma)'(0)$$

and where $p =\gamma(0).$

The attempt at illustrating this construct imagines the function $f(x,y)= e^{-\left((x+ 2.13)^2+(y+1.16)^{2}\right)}$ (a bivariate Gaussian bell curve) representing the density of historically relevant buildings and monuments at any given point in the city of Paris (from [this site](https://parismap360.com/paris-tourist-map)):

[image]

The chart used that allows Cartesian coordinates imposed on the manifold is centered at the Louvre $(0,0),$ and the function $f$ happens to have its maximum around des Champs-Élysées, so that we expect the density of historical buildings to start decreasing away from that point.

[image]

This function is evaluated along a curve $\gamma(t)= -0.16(t +2.5)^2 +1$ which when mapped onto the chart is $\gamma(t)=(t, -0.16(t +2.5)^2 +1).$ It roughly follows the Seine river in the center of Paris. The Louvre is the point $p=\gamma(0)=(0,0).$ The velocity vector or tangent at a point is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -0.32(t+2.5)\end{bmatrix}^\top,$ or in the chart, $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -0.32(x+2.5)\end{bmatrix}^\top.$

For the attempted (are they correct (?)) calculations the composition $f\circ \gamma$ is expressed as $f(a(t), b(t)).$

$$\begin{align}
\small X_pf &= (f\circ \gamma)'(t=0) \\[2ex]
&=\left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left(x(t),y(t)\right) \, 
\color{red}{x'(t)}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x(t),y(t)\right)\,\color{red}{y'(t)}\right]\Bigg|_{t=0} \\[3ex]
&= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\end{bmatrix}^\top \color{red}{\underset{\text{tangent vector }\\\text{(velocity)}}{\begin{bmatrix}x'(0)\\y'(0)\end{bmatrix}}}  \\[3ex]
& = \left. \begin{bmatrix}-2 (x + 2.13) e^{(-(x + 2.13)^2 - (y + 1.16)^2)} \\  -2 (y + 1.16) e^{(-(x + 2.13)^2 - (y + 1.16)^2)}\end{bmatrix}^\top\right|_{p=\gamma(0)}\small\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}x'(0) \\ y'(0)\end{bmatrix}} \\[3ex]
&=\small{ 2 (t + 2.13) e^{-(t + 2.13)^2 - ((-0.16 (t + 2.5)^2 + 1) + 1.16)^2} \\ + (-2 ((-0.16 (t + 2.5)^2 + 1) + 1.16) e^{-(t + 2.13)^2 - ((-0.16 (t + 2.5)^2 + 1) + 1.16)^2)}(-0.32 (t + 2.5)) \Big|_{t=0}}\\[2ex]
&=-0.00670189
\end{align}$$

Comment: Write $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$, nothing with $a(t), b(t)$; $f$ has no idea what those mean. And evaluate the partials at $p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your feedback. It means that the example might not be completely silly to give an intuition about the main characters in this construct. Your comment hits at the the main problem I'm encountering as a layperson - translating into rigorous math an intuition. Could you consider an edit to the post including these ideas?

Comment: @TedShifrin I wanted to present the linearity as a dot product, where the second vector is the tangent to the curve, contributing the "derivative of the inside" to the chain rule implicit in the calculation, but I can't see how to build this explicit dot product without using something like this silly $a(t), b(t).$

Comment: @TedShifrin Is the edited version closer to your suggestion?

Comment: No. Nothing with $t$. You are composing $f$, a function of $(x,y)$, with the function $\gamma$, a function of $t$.

Comment: You need to evaluate the derivative of $f$ at $p=\gamma(0)$ and the derivative of $\gamma$ at $t=0$. I will edit somewhat.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! I thought (incorrectly) that is what I was doing while preserving the vector of the tangent at a point as a vector ready to dot product with the Jacobian of the function.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it now correct - after your edit?

Comment: The display is totally messed up. This is why I don't edit other people's math. Your Paris tour example is totally charming, however. :)

Comment: Can you go back and fix the line break in the middle of the align? Sorrrrry.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I did fix that small part - it's my fault! I try to compensate for my lack of mathematical knowledge by over-embellishing the $\LaTeX$ to make it clearer, but it gets in the way of editing. Thank you very, very much. I will assume that now it is conceptually correct. Does it reflect the idea of linearity in the diff geom concept of tangent vector?

Comment: Yes, the approach is correct. I would not do the exposition/explanation this way, however. As I indicated at the beginning, I would NOT put in all the functions of $t$. Go back to the third line. Then compute $\gamma(0)=p$ and plug the point in (no functions of $t$). Compute the derivative $\gamma'(t)$, then evaluate at $0$, then work with that vector. The penultimate line (which caused me the trouble) shouldn't be there. Just numerical stuff at that point. As I said, your example is charming. Perhaps some of my YouTube lectures (see profile for link) might help you, too.

Comment: @TedShifrin Your help has already been invaluable, but it would be great to see it sketched out in your own notation to see unambiguously where the mathematical abuse took place in my attempt.

Comment: Not abuse. Just inefficiency and awkwardness ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here's how I would write it up cleanly.

The chain rule says that
$$(f\circ\gamma)'(0) = Df(\gamma(0))\gamma'(0) = Df(p)\gamma'(0).$$
We have $p=(0,0)$ and $\gamma'(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -.32(2.5)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -0.8\end{bmatrix}$. We also have, according to your formulas, $Df(p) = Df(0,0) \approx \begin{bmatrix} -0.01188 & -0.00647\end{bmatrix}$. Thus,
$$Df(p)\gamma'(0) \approx \begin{bmatrix} -0.01188 & -0.00647\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-0.8\end{bmatrix} \approx -0.01188 + 0.00647\cdot 0.8 \approx -0.0067.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! You were clear in your comments, but now there is zero room for mis-interpretations.